error after \begin{cases*}
What is wrong with the following code. It says "missing $ inserted".
\[
f_i(x_0,x_1)(t)=
\begin{cases*}
p_0(H_i(x_0,x_1,3t))   & if 0\leq t\leq \frac{1}{3} \\
\gamma_i(3t-1)         & if \frac{1}{3}\leq t\leq \frac{2}{3} \\
p_1(H_i(x_0,x_1,3-3t)) & if \frac{2}{3}\leq t\leq 1
\end{cases*}
\]


Please give a complete (minimal) example. Also, it does not hurt if it gets formatted a bit, so that it is easier to read.

Do remember that you need mathtools in order to use cases*. As you only provide a sniplet, we cannot see if you actually loaded mathtools.

I assume you're employing the mathtools package, as it defines an environment called cases*.
The cases* environment differs from the cases environment of the amsmath package in that the material to the right of the & symbols is assumed to be in text mode. To avoid getting syntax errors, you must enter and exit math mode for the math-y material that's to the right of the & symbols.

\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{mathtools}  % for 'cases*' env.

\begin{document}

\[
f_i(x_0,x_1)(t)=
\begin{cases*}
p_0(H_i(x_0,x_1,3t))   & if $0\leq t\leq \frac{1}{3}$ \\
\gamma_i(3t-1)         & if $\frac{1}{3}\leq t\leq \frac{2}{3}$ \\
p_1(H_i(x_0,x_1,3-3t)) & if $\frac{2}{3}\leq t\leq 1$
\end{cases*}
\]

\end{document}


You, just beat me in some seconds
